# RC circuit - Vc(t) calculus from integral with defined integral constant

Tags: circuit-analysis, remote-control

I have 2 questions :

From this i get differential equation :

[image]

I get

[image]

**1) Can I say that :**

[image]

[image]

**2) Or, maybe for complex circuit, I have to play with contants like that :**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about your questions, actually. The first one seems to be asking if the input source happens to be a constant (DC) voltage that is greater than zero, then will the voltage across the capacitor always be less than this value. And I'd say that given an infinite amount of time then they could be equal, but that in finite times you'd be right. But what are you really on about here?

Answer (score 2):

I really can't tell exactly what you'd like to know. But since you bring up a 'complex function' I decided to write something about annihilator methods, as they help me a lot when facing a more complicated input source. Here goes:

One way to see all this is about turning everything into homogeneous functions, which are really easy to solve. You can turn any non-homogeneous function into a homogeneous one by using annihilators.

For example, in your case we can write out the KCL as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{v_{_\text{OUT}}}{R}+C\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v_{_\text{OUT}}&=\frac{v_{_\text{IN}}}{R}
\\\\
\frac{v_{_\text{OUT}}}{R\,C}+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}v_{_\text{OUT}}&=\frac{v_{_\text{IN}}}{R\,C}
\\\\
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{OUT}}&=\left[\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{IN}}
\\\\
\left[D+\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{OUT}}&=\left[\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{IN}}
\end{align*}$$

Here, \$D=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\$, is just another way of writing the differential operator with respect to time.

The above isn't homogeneous. But if \$v_{_\text{IN}}\$ is a constant then it is really easy to make it homogeneous. Just multiply both sides by the constant annihilator **D** (you must be aware that the derivative of a constant is zero):

$$\begin{align*}
\bigg[D\bigg]\left[D+\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{OUT}}&=\bigg[D\bigg]\left[\frac1{R\,C}\right] v_{_\text{IN}}
\\\\
\bigg[D\bigg]\left[D+\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{OUT}}&=0
\end{align*}$$

Now it is homogeneous.

The zero for \$\left[D-\alpha\right]\$ is \$\alpha\$ so the general solution is \$A\,e^{^{\alpha\,t}}\$. If you see two multiplied together like that, it means you add two of the solutions together. So in this case I see the following: \$\left[D-0\vphantom{\frac{-1}{R\,C}}\right]\left[D-\frac{-1}{R\,C}\right]\$. So the general solution will be of the following form:

$$\begin{align*}
v_{_\text{OUT}} &=A_1\,e^{^{0\,t}}+A_2\,e^{^{\frac{-1}{R\,C}\,t}}
\\\\
&=A_1+A_2\,e^{^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}}
\end{align*}$$

Assuming that \$v_{_\text{C}}=v_{_\text{IN}}\$ at \$t=\infty\$, you can easily see that \$A_1=v_{_\text{IN}}\$. And assuming that \$v_{_\text{C}}=0\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0\$ then it also follows that \$A_2=-v_{_\text{IN}}\$. So the specific solution is:

$$\begin{align*}
v_{_\text{OUT}} &=v_{_\text{IN}}\left(1-e^{^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

But suppose \$v_{_\text{IN}}=V_0\cdot\cos\left(\omega\, t\right)\$? That's more complicated, right? What can be done to annihilate a cosine function??

Just multiply by \$\left[D^2+\omega^2\right]\$! You can easily see by applying the algebra that this will work in turning the new \$v_{_\text{IN}}\$ into zero.

So in this case:

$$\begin{align*}
\bigg[D^2+\omega^2\bigg]\left[D+\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{OUT}}&=\bigg[D^2+\omega^2\bigg]\left[\frac1{R\,C}\right] V_0\cos\left(\omega\,t\right)
\\\\
\bigg[D^2+\omega^2\bigg]\left[D+\frac1{R\,C}\right]v_{_\text{OUT}}&=0
\end{align*}$$

The zeros for \$\left[D^2+\omega^2\right]\$ are \$\pm i\,\omega\$. So the general solution is:

$$\begin{align*}
v_{_\text{OUT}} &=A_1\,e^{^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}}+A_2\,e^{^{i\,\omega\, t}}+A_3\,e^{^{-i\,\omega\, t}}+
\\\\
&=A_1\,e^{^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}}+\left(A_2+A_3\right)\cos\left(\omega\,t\right)+i\,\left(A_2-A_3\right)\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)
\end{align*}$$

And there are ways to get to the specific solution from there. (Note also that you can combine the two trig functions into a single one with an added phase.)

You can, of course, use methods of undetermined coefficients and/or integrating factors to solve. But annihilators are also handy to know about.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The differential equation tells us what is the stability of the system when t tends to infinity. The study of y'+2y=exp(-2x) gives us (D+2)^2. So a solution of the form c1 exp(-2 x) + c2 x exp(-2 x) but where is the particular solution because exp(-2 x) appears in yc and also in yp. It is known that y = yc + yp. Here yp=c2 x exp(-2 x) and yp'+2 yp=exp(-2x) gives us c2=1. And y(x)=c1 exp(-2 x) + x exp(-2 x) and so no matter how infinite c1 we have y'+2y=exp(-2x). So in your explanation A1=Vin when t goes to infinity will be deduced by studying the particular solution.